# Trying to understand Python maps

Tags: python

I have not really used `maps` before in my programming experience, so I am having trouble understanding the more `complex versions of maps`. So let's say that the problem is you are given an integer in minutes, in this case `n = 808`. What you are to do with this number is convert it to `24 hour time`, so `hh:mm`. This would give you `13:28`. Once this is done, add up the digits of that time to get the answer. So, the `answer would be 14`. I saw a really nice one-liner to this solution and I am trying to understand it because my solution took about `5 more lines of code`.

This is the solution:

```
sum(map(int, str(n // 60 * 100 + n % 60)))
```

So I understand that maps apply the same function over an iteration of numbers, but what `throws me off is the int,str(...) part`. I am not sure what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @pstatix how do you then get from `1328` to `14` as the answer?

Comment: @PeterWood 1 + 3 + 2 + 8

Comment: just extract the `str` and apply it outside of the map.

Comment: @RafaelC but how do you get from `1328` to `1, 3, 2, 8`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two mathematical operators used here:

- `//` represents floor division, i.e. extract the integer portion of the result after division.
- `%` represents modulus, i.e. the remainder after division.

Therefore, for `n = 808`, the algorithm returns:

```
str(808 // 60 * 100 + 808 % 60) = str(13 * 100 + 28) = '1328'
```

`map(int, '1328')` then takes each character in the string `'1328'` and converts it into an integer, itself returning an iterable. `map` requires an iterable as its second (and subsequent) arguments. Strings can be iterated to extract each character one at a time.

Finally, `sum` takes each of the integers returned from `map` and adds them together.

An equivalent formulation of the logic is possible via `sum` with a generator expression:

```
sum(int(i) for i in str(n // 60 * 100 + n % 60))
```

Comment: To clarify the behaviour of `map`, it expects an iterable as a second argument. And the string behaves as a list holding individual characters.

Answer (score 2):

`map` ,as you stated, applies a function over a *iterable*.

So, when you do

```
map(int, str(n // 60 * 100 + n % 60))
```

You are using the function `int` over the iterable `str(n // 60 * 100 + n % 60)`. As you probably know, strings are iterables (because, of course, you can iterate over them) - that can be easily checked

```
for char in "abcd":
    print(char)

a
b
c
d
```

The return from `str(n // 60 * 100 + n % 60)` is `'1328'`. When you apply `int` to each char, you transform each to an integer. You can easily see this by instead of taking the `sum` right away, getting a lsit

```
list(map(int, str(n // 60 * 100 + n % 60)))

[1, 3, 2, 8]
```

I guess now it is easy to see that the `sum` will get the sum of these numbers, which is what you wanted from the beginning :)

Comment: @pstatix yes. But the idea, as OP stated, is to sum every digit of the resulting number :) So you don't want the integer 1328, but the sum of these digits

Comment: @pstatix No. using `int` on the string will return the integer 1328.

Answer (score 0):

Both `int()` and `str()` are functions. In this particular example, when `n=808` the argument to the `str()` function is calculated as 1328, which when converted to the string becomes `'1328'`. A string is iterable, so the `map` function is simply applying `int` to each character of the string, producing the sequence `[1,3,2,8]`.